# jQuery selector to get last child that doesnt have a class

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have a page of nested `UL`s and `LI`s, I need to get the last `LI` of each `UL`, so I'm doing:

```
$('li:last-child')
```

this works great.

But I need to extend this so it gets the last child `LI` of each `UL`, where the `LI` doesn't have a given class (`x`). For example:

```
<ul>
    <li class="x">1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li class="x">3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li class="x">
        6
        <ul>
            <li class="x">7</li>
            <li>8</li>
            <li class="x">9</li>
            <li>10</li>
            <li>11</li>
            <li class="x">12</li>
            <li class="x">13</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to return `LI` 5 and 11 (as these are the last children within their parent `ul` that don't have `.x`)

How can I do this elegantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`map()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method to create a jQuery object by iterating over the `<ul>` elements, and returning the last child `<li>` element without an `x` class.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/e2Da7/2/

```
var lastLisNoX = $('ul').map(function() {
    return $(this).children('li:not(.x)').get(-1);
});
```

---

**EDIT:** *Updated my jsFiddle example with the HTML that was posted in the question.*

Answer (score 0):

Filter out the elements with a class.

```
$('li:not(.x):last-child')
```

If the classes are different amongst the li elements, that is if all the elements are not `class="x"` then something like

```
$('li[class=""]:last-child')
```

Comment: this wont work, because if the last element is `x`, `last-child` wont select the nearest, previous `li` that isnt `x`